# Why doesn't for_each_process show every task?

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, task

I am trying to loop through every process in a *`/proc`* utility I'm writing (a kernel module in *`/fs/proc`*). The problem is, I am only seeing processes in the root namespace. I'm trying to use the macro `for_each_process()` from `sched.h`.

I can type `ps` in a shell and see plenty of processes, but my `for_each_process()` loop doesn't see them. What gives?

**Note:** I am wondering if it has something to do with `rcu_read_lock()`? I'm afraid to put an `rcu_read_lock()` and I don't know where it should go. The trouble is, the [documentation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rcupdate.h?a=arm#L594) I read seems to say that in a preemptive kernel (mine is), it is illegal to sleep inside of `rcu_read_lock()`. I need to call `down_read(mmap_sem)` which I am afraid will sleep. So that means I can't use `rcu_read_lock()`?

Comment: My gut feeling is that this could be a permission thing ? what happens if you run  your utility with su/sudo ? I take it that this is a C program ?

Comment: Also seems that this example is showing similar results:  http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-foreachprocess-in-proc-entry.html

Comment: Ignore my first, didn't realise this was a kernel module.

Comment: Just wrap it: `rcu_read_lock(); for_each_process(p) { ... }; rcu_read_unlock();`, like it's done in `fs/exec.c`. Of course you do need the RCU read lock, or processes may disappear catastrophically while traversing the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should show you all the processes. I have written code like this.

```
struct task_struct *task;

for_each_process(p) {
    printk("Task %s (pid = %d)\n",p->comm, task_pid_nr(p));
}
```

This is printing all the processes. I suspect your `proc_read` function. Can you paste your `proc_read` function over here?

Answer (score 4):

I think `for_each_process()` just gives you the thread group leader.

This iterates over all `task_struct` variables (defined in sched.h).

```
struct task_struct *g, *p;
do_each_thread(g, p) {
    //do something with p
} while_each_thread(g, p);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example prints out a long list, looks like it might be printing almost all of them....thought I have not counted them

http://tuxthink.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-foreachprocess-in-proc-entry.html

Answer (score -2):

`for_each_process` is a kernel layer function, and it's really not how you're supposed to loop over processes in unix.  Something a lot simpler, such as this (python, easily implemented in other languages), might be the solution you want.

```
#Print each process id
import re,os
for fn in os.listdir( '/proc' ):
    if re.match('\d+', fn):
        print 'process %s'%fn
```

Comment: It's a good point - but if he's looking to enumerate /proc, then there's probably a reason you want to ignore userland processes ? Just guessing anyway, Robert might want to explain a bit more.

Comment: I am writing a module that will live in proc, i.e. I access it by `cat /proc/list_of_procs`. So I need a kernel layer function.